# Is there a better media player library that supports subtitles and hls for android than google's exoplayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, subtitle, exoplayer

I am trying to build an app that streams videos via hls and need to support subtitles up till now I am testing my app on .srt files.
I have seen google's library [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) but it has some complex installation then found an exoplayer wrapper "[ExoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia)" which worked perfectly except that it is not supporting subtitles. Then I decided to add the support in Exomedia which worked well but the encoding of .srt file has some issues (some turkish characters appear as ؟ when trying to read as iso or � when trying to read as utf-8).
So I have been wondering if there is an already built library that supports subtitles and http streaming.

**EDIT**

The subtitle problem was that Exoplayer only supports UTF-8 encoded subtitles and the srt file I was supplying was not UTF-8 encoded

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: No, I worked with ExoMedia and added my own adjustments to it, turned out to be a quite good  library.

Comment: How do you add subtitles to the HLS in exoMedia?